# Encrypting password over https that was initally not encrypted - pros and cons

Tags: security, encryption, https, md5

I have a popular app that i inherited where the users credentials are sent bare over the wire to an authenticating end point.  Now i have a task to 'hash' the credentials to prevent man in the middle attacks etc.  as you now https was compromised a little while ago so anything is possible and being secure is better.

Now, imagine if i md5(password) then since its one way i cant decrypt at the authenticating end point.  This means that all the current users would have to reset there password so i could hash it again.

What is the best approach in this matter to handle the case where users password was not encrypted in the beginning but now should be ?

Comment: Hashing absolutely does not prevent man-in-the-middle.  As stated below, you need to fix TLS.  If your app is as popular as you say, I strongly recommend requiring everybody to change their passwords.  You should also read up on [Salted Password Hashing](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm) because you are misunderstanding some important concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to fix your TLS setup. If you cannot trust your TLS connection, you cannot really trust anything that runs in the browser either.

As you still confuse MD5 with encryption, I would seriously advice you against creating your own password hashing protocol.

Comment: your right md5 is not encryption since its one way.  Its a hash function.  i think the best way is just to encrypt and decrypt on the other end.  thanks for the help.

Comment: If you encrypt, use asymmetric encryption and send the public key for encryption. That's not that secure as an attacker may still replace it with another public key, but at least that's an active attack, instead of a passive one where an attacker just has to view the bytes in transit.

Comment: Disagree with "Alternatively you could put your current password hashing method in the browser and then add an additional level of password hashing at the server" -- this is vulnerable to "pass the hash" attacks.  In other words, TLS is absolutely required to fix this problem.  See [Method to Protect Password in Databases for Web Applications](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/387.pdf)

Comment: OK, that makes sense... I'll remove that option. Thanks for the warning TheGreatContini.